# getting issue while conecting the MS SQL server remotely through java code

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc-odbc

This is my code for connecting to the  Server remotely.
One thing more i would like to tell you guys that this code works only i am within my home network (the network in which server is installed) but i am unable to access it from other network
    hey guys please fix it thanks in advance

```
public class SQLServerDemo
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here

        try {
            System.out.println("Hello from try");

            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.0.2:1433;user=demo;password=demo;databaseName=SQL_Demo";

            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            if (conn != null)
            {
                System.out.println("Connected");
            } else if (conn == null)
            {
                System.out.println("NotConnected");
            }
            String queryString = "select * from UserDetail";
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Exception**

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host GAUTAM-VAIO, port 1433 has failed.
Error: "null. Verify the connection properties.
Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port.
Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
```

Comment: You are not using public ip.

Comment: so suggest me how to use public ip and where should i use in code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use 192.168.0.2:1433, it's valid only in your internal LAN network.

You have to find your external IP out of your LAN.

Comment: i have used 27.7.38.166 also which is my public ip but getting same problem guys